# How can I use Michel Fortin's PHP Markdown Without Autoloading?

Tags: php, markdown, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

I want to use [Michel Fortin's PHP Markdown parser](http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/). The new style requires the user to set up a PSR-0-compatible autoloader. However, the instructions also state:

> If you don’t want to use autoloading you can do a classic require_once to manually include the files prior use instead.

Unfortunately there are no instructions on simply using require_once. I don't want to use an autoloader, how can I use this Markdown parser to parse my string of Markdown?

---

**EDIT:** Also, is it possible to use the parser with `require_once` inside a function (and outside the global scope)? The problem with `use` is it must be used globally which seems to make `require_once` required in the global scope. My preference is to only `require_once` if necessary in a function and outside the global scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really only two files you might need to require.

For regular Mardown:

```
require_once '/path/to/code/Michelf/Markdown.php';

$my_html = \Michelf\Markdown::defaultTransform($my_text);
```

Or for Markdown Extra:

```
require_once '/path/to/code/Michelf/MarkdownExtra.php';

$my_html = \Michelf\MarkdownExtra::defaultTransform($my_text);
```

Comment: Thanks. I had `require_once` and `use` inside a function which was causing my problem. Is there any way to avoid `use \Michelf\Markdown;` altogether here so I can `require_once` inside a function? My preference is to `require_once` only if necessary and that means putting `require_once` in a function outside the global scope which apparently I can't do because it must be declared before `use` which must be in the global scope.

Comment: You can use the fully qualified names of the classes. I've edited my answer above to reflect that.